# Applicative validation syntax scalaz + shapeless 2.0

Tags: scala, scalaz, shapeless, applicative, scalaz7

I'm trying to convert this [Applicative validation syntax](http://meta.plasm.us/posts/2013/06/05/applicative-validation-syntax/) example into Scalaz 7 + Shapeless 2.0

```
//for jupyter-scala kernel
//classpath.add("org.scalaz" %% "scalaz-core" % "7.2.7")
//classpath.add("com.chuusai" %% "shapeless" % "2.3.2")

case class Foo(a: Int, b: Char, c: String)
```

First the Scalaz syntax

```
import scalaz._
import Scalaz._

type ErrorsOr[A] = ValidationNel[String, A]
type Validator[A] = String => ErrorsOr[A]

val checkA: Validator[Int] = (s: String) =>
   try s.toInt.success catch {
   case _: NumberFormatException => "Not a number!".failureNel
}

val checkB: Validator[Char] = (s: String) =>
  if (s.size != 1 || s.head < 'a' || s.head > 'z') {
    "Not a lower case letter!".failureNel
  } else s.head.success

val checkC: Validator[String] = (s: String) =>
  if (s.size == 4) s.success else "Wrong size!".failureNel


def validateFoo(a: String, b: String, c: String) =
    (checkA(a) |@| checkB(b) |@| checkC(c))(Foo.apply _)

println(validateFoo("ab", "cd", "ef"))  
//Failure(NonEmpty[Not a number!,Not a lower case letter!,Wrong size!])
println(validateFoo("42", "cd", "ef")) 
//Failure(NonEmpty[Not a lower case letter!,Wrong size!])

def validateFoo2(a: String, b: String, c: String):Validation[NonEmptyList[String], Foo] = 
  checkC(c) <*> (checkB(b) <*> (checkA(a) map (Foo.apply _).curried))

println(validateFoo2("42", "cd", "ef")) 
//Failure(NonEmpty[Not a lower case letter!,Wrong size!])
```

So far so good, now into Shapeless 2.0

```
import shapeless._
import shapeless.ops.hlist._
import shapeless.ops.function._
import shapeless.poly._
import shapeless.syntax.std.function._

object applier extends Poly2 {
  implicit def ap[F[_]: Applicative, H, T <: HList, R]:
    Case2.Aux[applier.type, F[(H :: T) => R], F[H], F[T => R]] =
    at[F[(H :: T) => R], F[H]](
      (f, fa) => fa <*> f.map(hf => (h: H) => (t: T) => hf(h :: t))
    )
}

class Lifter[F[_]: Applicative] {
  def lift[G, H, A <: HList, M <: HList, R](g: G)(implicit
    hlG: FnToProduct.Aux[G, A => R],
    mapped: Mapped.Aux[A, F, M],
    unH: FnFromProduct.Aux[M => F[R], H],
    folder: LeftFolder.Aux[M, F[A => R], applier.type, F[HNil => R]]
  ) = unH((m: M) => folder(m, hlG(g).point[F]).map(_(HNil)))
}

def into[F[_]: Applicative] = new Lifter[F]

val liftedFoo = into[ErrorsOr] lift (Foo.apply _)

def validateFooGeneric(a: String, b: String, c: String) =
  liftedFoo(checkA(a), checkB(b), checkC(c))

println(validateFooGeneric("42", "cd", "ef"))
//Failure(NonEmpty[Not a lower case letter!,Wrong size!])
```

Now the final bit

```
    def validate[F[_], G, H, V <: HList, I <: HList, M <: HList, A <: HList, R]
  (g: G)(v: V)(implicit
  hlG: FnToProduct.Aux[G, A => R],
  zip: ZipApply.Aux[V, I, M],
  mapped: Mapped.Aux[A, F, M],
  unH: FnFromProduct.Aux[I => F[R], H],
  folder: LeftFolder.Aux[M, F[A => R], applier.type, F[HNil => R]],
  appl: Applicative[F]
) = unH((in: I) => folder(zip(v, in), hlG(g).point[F]).map(_(HNil)))
```

All compiling but when one attempts to use it, e.g.:

```
val validateFooShapeless = validate(Foo.apply _)(checkA :: checkB :: checkC :: HNil)
```

I get an error

```
could not find implicit value for parameter mapped: shapeless.ops.hlist.Mapped.Aux[A,F,M] 
validate(Foo.apply _)(checkA :: checkB :: checkC :: HNil) 
                     ^
```

Any ideas, pointers would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You need [SI-2712](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-2712) improvement for implicit search to work correctly on type lambdas (for example, `Validator[?]`). Update Scala to 2.11.11+ or 2.12.2+ and add the following to your build.sbt:

```
scalacOptions ++= Seq("-Ypartial-unification")
```

For 2.10.x, there's a [compiler plugin](https://github.com/milessabin/si2712fix-plugin), which you can activate with the following line in build.sbt:

```
addCompilerPlugin("com.milessabin" % "si2712fix-plugin_2.10.6" % "1.2.0")
```